# Retrieving each element of multiple arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I think this might be very easy to do, but I don't know exactly how I can.
Suppose that we have multiple arrays:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1, 3, 5, 7 ,9]
z = [1, 5, 10, 15, 20]
```

Then, how can I get each element of each array using the for loop? What I'm trying to do is something like the following:

```
for (x1, x2, x3) in (x, y, z):
  print (x1, x2, x3)
```

Of course, the above code block doesn't work. Could anyone tell me how I can do this?

Comment: are they always the same length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `x`, `y` and `z` are always the same length, you can use the built-in [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1, 3, 5, 7 ,9]
z = [1, 5, 10, 15, 20]

for (x1, x2, x3) in zip(x, y, z):
    print(x1, x2, x3)
```

**Output**

```
(1, 1, 1)
(2, 3, 5)
(3, 5, 10)
(4, 7, 15)
(5, 9, 20)
```

If `x`, `y` and `z` are not of the same length then `zip()` will return a list of tuples truncated in length to `min(len(x), len(y), len(z))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `zip` function that creates a list of tuples:

```
>>> zip(x,y,z)
[(1, 1, 1), (2, 3, 5), (3, 5, 10), (4, 7, 15), (5, 9, 20)]
```

Zip thus generates - for the given lists - a list of tuples such that tuple *T<sub>i</sub>* consists out of the elements *X<sub>i</sub>*, *Y<sub>i</sub>* and *Z<sub>i</sub>*.

Next you can iterate over these tuples:

```
for (x1, x2, x3) in zip(x, y, z):
  print (x1, x2, x3)
```